# How to extract sub element as String from XML

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I have a XML in String format:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ns4:DataRequest xmlns:ns4="urn:com:sony:xsd:DataRequest001" xmlns:ns2="urn:com:sony:xsd:pay001" xmlns:ns3="urn:com:sony:xsd:common">
   <Hdr>
      <Date>2021-01-28T13:29:00</Date>
      <CallType>Item_Check</CallType>
      <CallSubType>TFT</CallSubType>
      <CallId>12345</CallId>
   </Hdr>
   <Pld>
      <SpecData>
         <MainSpec>
            <AppId>123</AppId>
            <Size>123</Size>
            <Amt>2000</Amt>
            <Payld>&lt;data&gt;&lt;id&gt;Id001&lt;/tag&gt;&lt;/data&gt;</Payld>
         </MainSpec>
      </SpecData>
   </Pld>
</ns4:DataRequest>
```

I am extracting payld using the below code:

```
String payload = null;

XMLStreamReader reader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(xmlAsString));

while (reader.hasNext()) {
    reader.next();
    if (reader.isStartElement()) {
        if ("payld".equalsIgnoreCase(reader.getLocalName())) {
            payload = reader.getElementText();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Now want to extract SpecData tag value in a string something like:

```
String specData = "<MainSpec><AppId>....</AppId><MainSpec>";
```

new to XMLStreamReader, not getting how this can be achieved.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
String specData = null;
String payload = null;

XMLStreamReader reader = xmlInputFactory.createXMLStreamReader(new StringReader(xmlAsString));

while (reader.hasNext()) {
    reader.next();
    if (reader.isStartElement()) {
        if ("appId".equalsIgnoreCase(reader.getLocalName())) {
            specData = reader.getElementText();
            continue;
        }
        else if ("payld".equalsIgnoreCase(reader.getLocalName())) {
            payload = reader.getElementText();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```